# Actualizar dos elementos diferentes con Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html5, ajax

Amigos, quisiera actualizar dos elementos diferentes con Ajax en una sola peticion:

```
$.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "bifrost/save_enroll.php",
         data: {
           aOperation: "searchByName",
           aDataStudent: $("#iSearchByName").val()
         },
         datatype: "text",
         success: function (a) {
           try {
             let json = $.parseJSON(a);
             AlertMessage(json.valores, json.codigo);
           } catch (t) {
             $("#tDataStudent").html(a);
             $("#ComboBoxStudent").html(a);
           }
         }
       });
```

"a" viene a ser la data que recibo y esa data es codigo HTMl, pero en ambos id's reciben la misma data, quisiera Devolver un Array para que pueda escoger por posicion y cargar en diferentes elementos del DOM, pero no acepta codigo HTML en un array, sólo valores. uso siempre json_encode() para devolver datos.

Alguna idea amigos, ya que en cada petición Ajax sólo puedo actualizar un elemento del DOM cuando devuelvo codigo HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Edito para que no se considere de baja calidad. Prueba con esto, básicamente lo único que hice fue cambiar el `datatype` por `json`:

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "bifrost/save_enroll.php",
     data: {
       aOperation: "searchByName",
       aDataStudent: $("#iSearchByName").val()
     },
     // cambiar datatype a ´json´
     datatype: "json",
     success: function (a) {
       // prueba con un console log para verificar que te esta retonando un array
       console.log(a);
       try {
         let json = $.parseJSON(a);
         AlertMessage(json.valores, json.codigo);
       } catch (t) {
         $("#tDataStudent").html(a);
         $("#ComboBoxStudent").html(a);
       }
     }
   });
```

Comment: Las respuestas que no tienen código o que son este en su gran mayoría se consideran de baja calidad, por favor lee [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), esta publicación parece más un comentario que una respuesta, en cuanto tengas suficiente [reputacion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en todas partes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)